# Need help identifying this old style fuse box

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m in the middle of replacing this 30 amp fuse box, but I’m not sure if this is that safest way to just replace with the same fuse box or if they even make it to this day.to be honest it looks over loaded. I'm not sure what kind of breakers these are due to one having a connecting plate on the outside of it. Any insight is appreciated this look before my time. Thank you for your time... aloha.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mark where are you located in the world. I see a serious concern in the photo (the 30 amp fuse on a 120v leg) if split phase 240v. I would be suggesting a breaker panel upgrade and getting more circuits of the proper size for the wiring.

Comment: One picture has fuses, the other two have breakers (I think).  Are these two different boxes?

Comment: Thanks Ed I’m from Hawaii but the house is from the late 80’ early 90’s my grandmothers home

Comment: Yes their are two different boxes.. one box is the 30 amp fuse boxe. The other is a dual 120/240 breaker box

Comment: You certainly don't need to replace a true fuse box (with actual fuses rather than breakers) with another true fuse box.  The only exception is some outdoor heat pumps or air conditioning units that want the faster protection of fuses rather than breakers, but those are usually installed at the outdoor unit disconnect.   Clearly you have some "old stuff" there and should be upgraded. Hate to say it, but it might be more than a DIY job.   But if you want to do it, we're here to help.

Comment: You will definitely want to replace the red-cloth-covered wire in the second pic. The insulation has completely worn away exposing the conductor inside. That can cause a nasty shock to someone who is working inside the box. Also, you said the house was built in the 80s/90s. Was it the _18_ 80/90s? Both of these boxes look _much_ more than 40 years old!

Comment: I'll get snipped for this, but many people refer to "fuse boxes" when they are really breaker panels.   My definition of a fuse box is where the house wires fuse to the incoming power. ;)   LOL   moderators, feel free to delete this comment after a few have gotten a laugh out of it.   Take care and wire on.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson a "fuse box" has fuses in it, like the first picture. A "breaker box" has circuit breakers in it, like the 2nd picture. Many people refer to both as a "fuse box" because that's what their parents/grand-parents called it before breakers became much more common. That said, I do get your reference to fused wires... ;) (just trying to help out the newer folks...)

Comment: @FreeMan I was thinking the same thing. That is not 40 years old unless some DIYer repurposed a very old box that was laying around, but even that doesn't make sense bc the wiring looks so old. I've seen stuff like this at my parents farm from the 1940s, fortunately none of it was in service. But yeah, you're right, it's way older than 40 years.

Comment: @FreeMan    LOL   I totally get that, I was just trying to make a joke!  The one thing that really bugs me is so many people refer to electrical problems as "shorts" as in short circuit, while you and I and many others know most electrical problems are OPEN CIRCUITS!  Oh well, what can you do.   Like your posts and agree with most all of 'em .

Comment: I suspect this may be a house built earlier (40s or 50s) that had a major upgrade in the 80s or 90s - perhaps add-on a section (doubling the size of the house) plus renovate the outside of the older section to match. That is quite common in some areas because it is cheaper than a teardown and less "can't live there at all" time. That can easily explain old fuse box + newer breaker panel.

Comment: Honestly, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, While that breaker panel may be "newer" it's not exactly _new_. It looks like it's from the 40's too!

Comment: @FreeMan You are very possibly correct. Or it might be 40s for one and 50s for the other + renovation done in the 80s *without* electrical upgrades.

Comment: Can you get us some zoomed-out shots of what's going on in addition to the super-closeups? We also can use photos of any factory *labeling* still present on either box

Comment: Also, what does that "fuse box" (it's a device called a *safety switch*, btw, and isn't as obsolete as it sounds as similar fused switches are still made to this day) turn on and off/protect?

Comment: @MarkKeali'iRita -- are you still with us? We'll need a better overall view of the hardware you have here to give you good advice about it, especially with the apparent age of that breaker box